# Passing a file parameter to a java agent

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, javaagents

I am writing a java agent and I need to pass it a file (`agent.properties`) as a parameter, under the `src/main/resources` directory.

To launch my spring-boot app with the agent, I do

`java -javaagent:/path/to/agent/myagent.jar=agent.properties MySpringBootApp`

When I try to open the file, my `InputStream` is always null. I don't know in which ClassLoader to read the file.

Here is my code :

```java
public class MyAgent
{
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst)
    {
        loadFile(agentArgs);
    }

    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation)
    {
       loadFile(agentArgs)
    }

    private static void loadFile(String agentArgs) {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = MyAgent.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(agentArgs);
        String fileContent = toString(resourceAsStream);
        System.out.println(fileContent);
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't know in which ClassLoader to read the file. I tried many solutions, I even tried `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(agentArgs);`

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You do not know the working directory at launch?

Comment: Yes, I start the agent within a Spring boot app. I passed the full path of the agent